# How can I export graphs based on conditions to PDF?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to come up with a VBA code excel to help me do the following:

1. Starting from Row 3, I am going iterate down a column (Starting from A4) which will change the value of a fixed row of cells (A2) - i.e Cell A2=A4,5,6, ... .
2. Based on the value of E2, it will only show 2/6 graphs (There are only 3 values of E2 possible, which each value showing 2/6 graphs)
3. Export the visible chart to a single PDF
4. Move on to the next row, repeat steps 2-3.

Here's my current code. However, I always received an error which says "Document not saved" and it does not go beyond the first row which I am iterating through.I am relatively new to VBA and do not have much experience in it. May I check if anyone here could help me with this please? Thank you so much

```vb
Sub GenerateGraphsAndExportPDFs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chartObject As chartObject
    Dim outcomeRange As Range
    Dim outcomeCell As Range
    Dim outcome As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pdfFolder As String
    Dim wbPath As String
    Dim wbName As String
    
    ' Set the worksheet to work with
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary") ' Change "Sheet1" to your actual sheet name
    
    ' Set the outcome range
    Set outcomeRange = ws.Range("E4:E" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    ' Prompt user to select a folder for saving PDFs
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            pdfFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub ' User canceled folder selection
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Save the workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    
    ' Get the workbook path and name
    wbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    wbName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    
    ' Loop through each outcome cell
    For Each outcomeCell In outcomeRange
        outcome = outcomeCell.Value ' Get the outcome from the cell
        
        ' Change the value in cell A2 to match the current cell in the outcome range
        ws.Range("A2").Value = outcomeCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        
        ' Show two out of six charts based on the outcome value
        Select Case outcome
            Case "1"
                ws.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Visible = True
                ws.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Visible = True
            Case "1/x"
                ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Visible = True
                ws.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Visible = True
            Case "1/x2"
                ws.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Visible = True
                ws.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Visible = True
            ' Add more cases for other outcomes as needed
        End Select
        
        ' Create a temporary worksheet
        Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
        Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        
        ' Copy and paste visible charts to the temporary worksheet
        Dim tp As Double
        Dim chrt As chartObject
        tp = 10 ' Adjust the initial top position
        For Each chrt In ws.ChartObjects
            If chrt.Visible Then
                chrt.CopyPicture
                wsTemp.Paste
                Selection.Top = tp
                Selection.Left = 10 ' Adjust the left position
                tp = tp + Selection.Height + 50
                Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Clear the clipboard
            End If
        Next chrt
        
        ' Export the temporary worksheet to PDF
        Dim pdfFileName As String
        pdfFileName = pdfFolder & "\" & ws.Range("A2").Value & "_Charts_" & outcome & ".pdf"
        wsTemp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        
        ' Delete the temporary worksheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wsTemp.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
        ' Hide all charts for the next iteration
        For Each chartObject In ws.ChartObjects
            chartObject.Visible = False
        Next chartObject
    Next outcomeCell
End Sub
```